# How to authenticate OS X app user against Active Directory?

Tags: objective-c, macos, active-directory

My OSX application presents user with a login screen. How can I validate the user entered credentials against an Active Directory? I have not found any inbuilt objective c api to achieve this. I checked for third party libraries and haven't found anything relevant yet.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to my own question. This can be done using Open Directory framework.Below 'setCredentials' method will return YES for correct username-password combination and NO otherwise

```
ODSession *mySession = [ODSession defaultSession];
NSError *err;
NSArray *nodeNames = [mySession nodeNamesAndReturnError:&err];
NSLog(@"nodeNames=%@", nodeNames);
ODNode *node = [[ODNode alloc] initWithSession:mySession name:@"Your domain 
name/node name" error:&err];
BOOL val = [node setCredentialsWithRecordType:nil 
recordName:@"username" password:@"password" error:&err];
```